# How can I turn either a Unix POSIX file descriptor or standard input Handle into a Socket?

Tags: networking, haskell, posix, inetd, systemd

In *inetd* and *systemd* type systems, it is possible for the system to bind a socket and launch the application with the socket already existing, for example to provide socket based service starting. I would like to take advantage of this functionality in one of my Haskell daemons.

The daemon currently calls, `socket`, `bindSocket`, `listen` to create a `Socket` object that I can later call `accept` on. To change this to an `inetd` type system I would need to use standard input as a `Socket`, but all I can find so far is `stdin :: Handle`, or `fdToHandle :: CInt -> Handle` - neither are quite what I need.

I can't seem to find anything that has type `Handle -> Socket`, nor anything that is like `stdin :: Socket`. The nearest I can find is `mkSocket` which is very low-level, and most other languages (ie, Ruby) provide a call to turn a file descriptor into a socket without having to specify various other parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C applications have the luxury of having `sd-daemon.h` which handles socket passing automatically. In Haskell, this file has to be emulated manually.

You can use [`stdInput`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unix/2.5.1.1/doc/html/System-Posix-IO.html#v%3astdInput) to get the `stdin` file descriptor. The [`handleToFd`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unix/2.5.1.1/doc/html/System-Posix-IO.html#v%3ahandleToFd) function can of course also be used. Since you want POSIX-specific behavior, you can't expect it to work on Windows, though.

Once you have the FD, you have no choice but to use the `mkSocket` function. Haskell can't guess what kind of socket that you want, so you have to specify it. You most probably want:

```
mkSocket fd AF_UNIX Stream defaultProtocol Listening
```

Please remember that this isn't necessarily how `systemd` passes file descriptors to your application. You must check the `LISTEN_FDS` and `LISTEN_PID` environment variables to see which file descriptors to use and whether its your job to even bind the sockets. The default file descriptor representing the default socket is FD 3, not FD 0 as you are assuming. `systemd` might also give you multiple sockets to use if the service file demands it.

Comment: Thanks! I think I might just end up writing a FFI to sd-daemon.h in the long run, but this should be enough to get me going. One quick question, why `NotConnected` over `Listening`? Is the socket not initially bound and setup to listen by systemd? Do I have to switch the socket into listening mode after calling `mkSocket`?

Comment: I interpreted the code in `sd-daemon.c` wrong. The socket is indeed in listening mode.

Comment: Ok, I finally have it working. Turns out AF_INET6 is the socket family, not AF_INET or AF_UNIX as I was expecting. I've edited your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The main trick for MkSocket is knowing you have the right parameters.  The sd-daemon.h helps with this.  I see from [systemd man page on sd_is_fifo](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_is_fifo.html) that it uses fstat and getsockname, the [code for sd_is_socket is in git here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/src/libsystemd-daemon/sd-daemon.c).

You can use `fstat` wrapped in the [unix package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix) to help

```
getFdStatus :: Fd -> IO FileStatus

isSocket :: FileStatus -> Bool
```

The Network package (partly using the Network.Socket.Internals) does also use the C `getsockname` function (the helper `withNewSockAddr` allocates the right buffer for the answer).  This require either guessing the "family" or perhaps just allocating a big buffer for the answer (`sockaddr_storage` from RFC 2553).  But Network takes the socket file descriptor from the `Socket` data.  You could pull out the code from Network and re-implement the checks that the sd-daemons.h does.

Also, the `getsockopt` code has probably been wrapped in the [network-socket-options package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-socket-options).

But it does not seem anyone has put it together quite the way you need.  Odd.